# How to call other methods in a class in django when self is not supplied as an argument

Tags: python, django

I come from PHP/Laravel Background where for calling methods or accessing properties within a class ,use of $this keyword is sufficient.In python3/Django4.0.6 i have to use request as first parameter to capture the request body
for eg.

```
class CustomAuth:

      def verifyToken(token):
          pass

      def login(request):
          data = request.body
          # how do i call verifyToken?
          # if i use self as first argument then i am not able to access the request
```

Comment: if you don't need `self` use the `@staticmethod` decorator. Otherwise `self` must be the first param

Comment: If you do not use the staticmethod decorator, the `request` will act as `self`, which is independent of the name.

Comment: The fact that you called your first argument `token` or `request` does not change the fact that it becomes the instance of the object. `self` is just a usual name for it. Change your method signature to `def login(self, request):`

Comment: yes as @MechanicPig and others pointed out irrespective of the name i am getting the first argument of type WSGIRequest object. now i am not getting the authservice self because maybe i am not instantiating it. need to check how actually the urls are mapped to functions in django! Thanks everyone!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be relatively standard based on what you are asking:

```py
class CustomAuth:

      def verifyToken(self, token):
          self.token = token
        

      def login(self, request):
            self.request = request
            data = request.body

            
            # how do i call verifyToken?
            x = self.verifyToken(self.token)
            # if i use self as first argument then i am not able to access the request
            r = self.request
```

Also, note the comments suggesting the `@staticmethod` method as an alternative.

Comment: Yes I tried that also. but taking "request" as second parameter does not return the request object. It is either or scenario. the "self" as first parameter lets me access the other methods and "request" as first parameter gives me the request object. none of them works on second position

Answer (score 0):

The point of "self" is to link the functions and variables to the instance.
If your function don't use class internal variables or other function you can decorate with @staticmethod and you will access it as usual.

For more details google it. [https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_self.asp#:~:text=The%20self%20parameter%20is%20a,that%20belongs%20to%20the%20class](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_self.asp#:%7E:text=The%20self%20parameter%20is%20a,that%20belongs%20to%20the%20class).

I find it strange the way you use the class.
Why don't you instantiate with parameter token, and don't need to use the function to assign token to internal class variable.

Comment: I have a class that handles the http requests and returns a json response. thus request is always the first argument for the given function. (somehow it does not work on second position like def login(self,request) this results in undefined request). now the problem is some methods are reused in other methods and they also act as an independent api end point. this positional argument seems a bit complicated. i also tried self.request that results in another error ('WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'request')

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone! the problem was that i was not instantiating the AuthService class.
earlier my urls.py for this auth module was like this

```
from django.urls import path

from .service import AuthService

urlpatterns = [
    path('login',AuthService.login,name='login'),
    
   
]
```

which i changed to this

```
from django.urls import path

from .service import AuthService

auth = AuthService()

urlpatterns = [
    path('login',auth.login,name='login'),
    
   
]
```

now this works fine

```
def login(self, request):
```